# Bash not honoring $PATH?

Tags: bash, caching

Under OS X 10.8.3, have an environment like this:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ echo $PATH
/Users/r/Desktop/Beryl/usr/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

There are two copies of `irb` in $PATH, as properly reported by `which`:

```
$ which -a irb
/Users/r/Desktop/Beryl/usr/bin/irb
/usr/bin/irb
```

But when I run `irb` I expect to get /Users/r/Desktop/Beryl/usr/bin/irb; instead I get /usr/bin/irb:

```
$ irb --version
irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)          # this is the wrong version
$ /Users/r/Desktop/Beryl/usr/bin/irb --version
irb 0.9.6(09/06/30)
$ /usr/bin/irb --version
irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)
```

I don't have any aliases.  I should mention that I launched bash by executing this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/Users/r/Desktop/Beryl/usr/bin:${PATH}
exec /bin/bash
```

Regardless, why is bash not running the first instance in $PATH?

Comment: Can you run `type irb` and tell us the output?

Comment: @fearless_fool `which` doesn't tell you what bash would actually do; `type` does. If there's an alias or a function, `type irb` will know about it.

Comment: @anubhava: I think you've got it: "$ type irb => irb is hashed (/usr/bin/irb)".  And I read the docs on bash / hash / type and I now understand why `which` didn't pick up the right one.  If you want to post an answer (`hash -r` will clean things up), I'll give you the checkmark.

Comment: @fearless_fool: That's great to know, I provided my answer as you suggested.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: you are correct sir! I'm old school (/bin/sh), back when `which` always told the truth and `rehash` would fix things. anubhava's comment has brought me into the 20th century...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following to determine from where irb is being executed:

```
type irb
```

To make bash shell to forget all remembered locations use:

```
hash -r
```

It appears that bash shell has previous location of `irb` saved in an internal hash.

Check here fore details about hash in bash: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hash.htm

Comment: That's exactly what happened: I ran the irb command (causing it to be hashed) then ran a build script that generated the new irb.  I expected bash to pick up the new version of irb, but of course it preferred the hashed one until I did a `hash -r`

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Answer (score 2):

It could be the hash that is causing the problem.  When you first run a program it reads `PATH`, but then `bash` saves the location in an internal hash.  It will use this hash subsequently (in the same session), regardless of the value of `$PATH`.

List existing locations with the `hash` command.

You can clear the hash with `hash -r`.

Edit:  see also the associative array `BASH_CMDS`.

Comment: This is a correct answer and I'll upvote it.  Anubhava was the first to suggest `type` (and hash), so I'll hold off on giving the check until I hear whether anubhava wants it or not.

Comment: as an aside, does anyone else believe that the OS X version of bash could use fsevent to efficiently invalidate the hash cache?  that would prevent this kind of astonishment...

Comment: @fearless_fool: I believe FSEvent is triggered only when the filesystem is changed.

Comment: @anubhava: that's correct.  and bash could use that to revalidate the hash if the fsevent occurred on any directory in $PATH.

Comment: (@cdarke: how weird that you and have have exactly the same number of rep points at this exact moment... :)

Comment: @fearless_fool: I think Apple just uses same source for Unix tools on Mac (doesn't mean they cannot change it though).